# What are possible ways to deal with a truly problematic player?

Tags: system-agnostic, problem-players

I am compiling a guide of "typical practices" among rpg groups (you can see it as an extension of the Same Page Tool but that also extends to logistical aspects).

I figure it would be useful to have a section about what to do if a player repeatedly betrays the group's social contract. When I saw this happens it always resulted into either the offender being kicked out or the campaign ending soon after (sometimes with broken friendships as a bonus). As such this section on my document is currently:

> What if a player repeatedly betrays the established social contract?
>
> - They have to leave, permanently. They have proven they can't be part of this game.
> - The game stops. It won't start until a satisfying solution has been found.

I think this item is important to include in my list because meeting truly awful players is a thing that happens and I wish I had been more ready to face it when it happened to me.

My issue is that I fail to imagine any other solution to the issue that doesn't involve the problem-player leaving the game (and thus making the second option like the first except the campaign is hold into ransom until the problem-player accepts to leave). I also don't want to simply write only one option unless it is absolutely consensual that nothing else could work.

I am looking for other legitimate ways to deal with those players (I am not talking about someone who did one thing wrong at some point: I am talking about the kind of player most people would consider irredeemable), or a confirmation that kicking them out is the only way to go.

Comment: List generation questions are rarely good for this site. With that said, most answers will involve talking to the player, but the details of that conversation will vary dramatically depending on the details as you will likely see if you search problem players here. This also makes any kind of concrete answer very difficult for a broad approach like this.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I admit this edges into "list" territory (although this list is unlikely to be more than 2 items long in my opinion), but I don't think "talk with the player" could work as one of this list's items. In the situation I describe you can assume the group members already did what they could to solve the issue but the problem persists. Maybe there is a way to talk this out but they don't know how.

Comment: An example of an item I thought about including in my list (but am reluctant to) would be "some players have immunity and can do whatever they please, others can leave if they are unhappy with that", which is de facto what happens in some groups.

Comment: This is an open ended discussion prompt, voting to close for “needs more focus”, though opinion based and needs details would apply too.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov i don't see why this would be broad, also what opinion would this be based on? and what details would you need? (about the opinion, I think there is plenty of room here, especially with the Good Subjective/Bad Subjective principle, to have quality answers.

Comment: This isn’t a real problem. “A player violates the social contract” is a vague, broad class of problems encompassing any number of more specific problems with different solutions, and what works for one situation might be wholly inappropriate for another, and your question leave us with no way of knowing what problems we are supposed to be matching solutions to. This just isn’t a good fit for the site as written.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov my question is not about me having a problem-player in one of my games, it is about what to write on my compilation of policies so that it is the most helpful possible. If you are positive that there are better policies than "kick the offender" *in some cases* (like, let's say, "if all of your players are left-handed 22 years old football players") then that could make a good answer. AFAIK there is no better policy than that but if there is one I need to be aware of it.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Please consider looking over the problem player tag and then see if you need a more specific question. A problem player who just stamps their foot and refuses to stop being a problem is rare and yes removal is about the only option. Most problem players involve misunderstandings to be cleared up or need practical help to stop with the problematic activities. There are lots of examples on this site. Most involve "talk to them" but how that conversation should start and what it involves can vary dramatically depending on the situation and some involve other things too.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman "A problem player who just stamps their foot and refuses to stop being a problem is rare and yes removal is about the only option" What I don't understand is how my question can be both not specific enough and also be so simple that you answer it without even trying to. This is not a snarky sarcastic comment: I seriously don't get it. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 6):

### Generally if a problem player keeps ruining the game for everyone and will not stop after a talk with the DM then removing them from the campaign is the only solution

You seem to already know this, if someone repeatedly acts in a way that the rest of the group considers unacceptable and refuses to stop, you need to either remove them from the group or the campaign will fall apart because nobody will want to play in it anymore. There is no secret ways of controlling someone who’s intent on being problematic, you can’t keep someone like that in the campaign.

If you are not the GM and the GM can’t/won’t kick the player out then the only options you have are to leave and possibly look for another group or stay and put up with it. No D&D is better than bad D&D and it’s generally better to remove yourself from the situation rather than stay in a game that’s making you miserable.

Comment: I agree with everything her in principal, but the cases where a player simply deliberately and blatantly refuses to behave properly are few and far between. They do happen, but its rare. Misunderstandings, a failure to be on the same page (sometimes to the point of effectively playing a different game) or unusual challenges with behaving properly, especially of the player is neurodivergent, are far more common.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman Yes. The very few times I have encountered this type of repetitive disruption have been with players who have had actual disabilities, perceptive or cognitive. It can be hard to tell if a hard-of-hearing player are talking over others because they aren't hearing them, or if they are "gaming" their disability to take more than their fair share of space.

Comment: @From sure, hence my recommendation to only do this *after* talking with the problematic player and trying to find another solution, in the end of the day though it doesn't matter *why* they're doing something if that something is making everyone else unhappy and they're refusing to stop. I can empathise with a player that has "challenges with behaving properly" but I still can't allow them to continue their improper behaviour if that's making everyone else miserable, they're not the only one at the table and it's my job as DM to keep everyone happy, not just one player